# 'ViewController' is not convertible to 'CocoaMQTTDelegate'?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, mqtt

I'm trying to set up a connection using CocoaMQTT. The following example is provided on the GitHub page:

https://github.com/emqx/CocoaMQTT/blob/master/Example/Example/ViewController.swift

They are using a view controller 'self' as the delegate (see lines 53/63/74). However, when I try to use the view controller as the delegate, I get the error:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'CocoaMQTTDelegate?'
```

I've tried converting it using:

```
self as! CocoaMQTTDelegate
```

But no dice.

In the example they are using a `ViewController: UIViewController` for iOS whereas I'm using a `ViewController: NSViewController` for macOS, could this be causing the issue? I'm pretty new to Swift so any help would be greatly appreciated. (It is an iOS/macOS/tvOS library).

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you comform the delegate by put this `ViewController: CocoaMQTTDelegate`

Comment: Did you add the extension as they do on line 126?

Comment: After adding those I'm just getting more and more errors, I'm starting to think maybe this 'example' isn't going to be as straight forward to implement as first expected.

Comment: @Cutter it's probably because you miss the other extensions as well, the code is extending ViewController further introducing the "TRACE" also extending "Optional" and TabBarDelegate. I have not tried, but it should work if you get all that code right?

Comment: @Vollan My bad... It now works. I was missing the extension. I was getting errors after adding it like you said because they make calls to other classes in their example workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Vollan for suggesting adding the extension at the bottom of the file. I probably should've noticed that. My bad.